# How do I hide a div or image after 20 seconds of flashing in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am busy making a memory game, where an image is to be displayed to the user, and after some 10 seconds of the image flashing, it should hide and four options are to be shown for the user to choose either the correct or incorrect answer.

So far, all I have accomplished is to load the images and cycle through all the puzzles that my code can find.
What I'm trying to do now is to make the image flash and hide after some time, while also just refreshing that section of the page, and not the entire page.

I am using C# and a user control on my page. 
What I have tried so far is only

```
<script> 
var x;
function BlinkImage() {
    x = 1;
    setInterval(change, 2000);
}

function change() {
    if (x === 1) {
        var image = document.getElementById('<%=imgMain.ClientID %>');
        image.visible = false;
        x = 2;
    }
    else {
        var image = document.getElementById('<%=imgMain.ClientID %>');
        image.visible = true;
        x = 1;
    }
}
</script>
```

And on loading my puzzle for that instance (in code behind)

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(game), "Start", "<script language=javascript> BlinkImage(); </script>");
```

Which does fire, as I can step through the code in debugging on Firefox. But my image does not flash or blink. I understand I am just using visiblity as my "blinker". I don't know what else to use exactly.

What can I do to make the image flash or blink for, say 20 seconds, then hide the image after that time has passed? Then repeat the process once the user has made a choice.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to apply a asp.net property `Visible` to a html object with javascript. That won't work. EIther change the image css class or set the style directly to the image.

Comment: you can try with `function change() { img = document.getEl..; img.opacity = x; x = (x === 1 ? 0 : 1); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following (comments in code):

```js
var blinkInterval = setInterval(change, 2000),   // set the interval into a variable
    image = document.getElementById('test'),     // replace test with your client id: <%=imgMain.ClientID %>
    x = 1;

function change() {
    if (x % 2 === 1) {  // see if it is odd or even by modding by 2 and getting remainder
        image.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        image.style.display = 'block';
    }
    
    x++; // increment x
    
    if (x === 10) {  // should have happened 10 times (which is 20 seconds with your intervals being at 2 seconds)
      clearInterval(blinkInterval); // clear the interval (should end hidden as odd is display none and we clear beforethe 20th is run)
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="test">test</div>
```

After the code has finished, wherever the user is making their selection, you just need to reset the `blinkInterval` variable:

```
blinkInterval = setInterval(change, 2000); // notice no need for the var declaration when you reset this
```

Comment: sorry for being so noobish, but how do i call these in code?

Comment: Add it in a script block on your page, or if it's in an external js file, just make sure the js file is included in the page

Comment: hm..., i'm getting an exception. typeerror, image is null. i'll play around a bit to get the var image to work

Comment: Not sure if this is still the case but sometimes with native js functions, you used to need to include the script after the element is inserted into the dom - you could try including the script before the closing body tag

Comment: that was it thanks. i moved it into a separate script tag at the bottom of my control, works like a charm. will now play around to speed it up.

Answer (score 1):

**Use style attribute and change if visible/hidden**

```
function change() {

var image = document.getElementById('<%=imgMain.ClientID %>');

    //check if visible   
    if (image.style.visibility=="visible") {

       image.style.visibility="hidden";
    }
    else {
       image.style.visibility="visible";
    }
}

;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function flashAndHide(img_id){
var img = $("#"+img_id);
var x = 0;
var inter = setInterval(function(){

if(x % 2 == 0){
img.hide();
}else{
img.show();
}
x += 1;
}



},1000);

if(x === 20){
img.hide();
clearInterval(inter);
}

  }
```

Haven't tested this, but it should work,